# how to play video file from a url in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to display this link in react native app running on ios 
I'm able to display jpg files using Image tag with no problem at all, however, the array being return from the API also contains video url as well something like this 'https://www.meteorshowers.org/view/iau-7', how can i go about showing it along with Images in a FlatList?

here is a link to what i am getting 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/hphm6natcfp5rey/Screenshot%202018-08-26%2017.47.57.png?dl=0' as you can see it's blank

```
`<TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  <Card 
   image={{ uri: item.hdurl }} 
   resizeMode='contain' 
   imageStyle={{ height: 300, }}
   />
<TouchableWithoutFeedback>`
```

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video

Answer (score 1):

You can use `'react-native-video'` module for this.

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';
...
<Video source={{uri: 'url_to_your_video'}} />
```